# How Apache-Tika server works in local device?

Tags: python, text, text-mining, apache-tika

I am new to the Apache-Tika server. I am trying to extract text from pdf using the Tika python package. It says that it calls the Tika server when we run the code. My question is, is it safe to use Tika? Will it upload my pdf files? How does this work? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The Python wrapper starts a local copy of the Apache Tika Server by default